# htaccess rewrite rule all requests to a file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can somebody help me with a rewrite rule?

I want to redirect all request to a file, however the redirect depends of a string in the url.

for example `http://domain.com/**v1**/something/something/?querystring` should be redirected to `/**v1**/index.php?q=something/something&querystring`

or

`http://domain.com/**v2**/something/something/?querystring` should be redirected to

`/**v2**/index.php?q=something/something&querystring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php?q=$2 [L,QSA]
```